# Solving an inequality induction

Tags: induction

For all:
$$ n \ge 6,   4n^2+1 < 3*2^n $$

p(n): $ 4n^2+1 < 3*2^n $

My work:

Basis Step: P(6) 145 < 192 is true

Induction Step: Let  $ n\ge 6 $, Assume $ 4(n+1)^2 +1 < 3*2^{n+1}$

What should I do next??

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to assume it is true for $n$, that is 
$$4n^2+1<3∗2^n,$$
and use that to prove that it is true for $n+1$, that is
$$4(n+1)^2+1<3∗2^{n+1}.$$

---

*Hint:* Notice that
$$4n^2+1<3∗2^n \implies\frac{4n^2+1}{3*2^{n}}<1,$$
and
$$4(n+1)^2+1<3∗2^{n+1}\iff \frac{4n^2+1}{3*2^{n}}+\frac{8n+4}{3*2^{n}}<2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Base case:** When $n=6$, we get $4\times 6^2+1 <3 \times 2^6 \iff 145<192$ which is right.

**Inductive step:** Assume that this ineqiality is true for when $n=k$, $\forall n\ge6$. To prove by induction, we want to show it's true for when $n=k+1$, and we are done.

So, when $n=k+1$, we get

$$ 4(k+1)^2+1<3\times2^{k+1}\iff 4(k^2+2k+1)+1<3\times 2^k\times 2$$
$$ \iff 2k^2+4k+5/2<3\times2^k$$
From our assumption, we know that $ 4k^2+1<3\times 2^k$, it suffices to just show that for $k\ge6$ that

$$ 2k^2+4k+5/2<4k^2+1 \iff 2k^2-4k-3/2>0 $$

Answer (score 0):

"Assume $4(n+1)^2+1<3∗2^{n+1}$".  No.  You assume it $4n^2 + 1 < 3*2^n$ and then you *PROVE* $4(n+1)^2 + 1 < 3*2^{n+1}$.

If we just noodle we get

$4(n+1)^2 + 1 = 4n^2 + 8n + 4 + 1 = (4n^2 + 1) + 8n + 4 < 3*2^n + 8n + 4$.

And that $3*2^{n+1} = 3*2^n*2 = 3*2^n + 3*2^n$.  So if we can prove $8n + 4 < 3*2^n$ we are done.

Or alternatively $3*2^{n+1} = 3*2^n + 3*2^n > (4n^2 + 1) + (4n^2 + 1)$.  So if we can prove $8n + 4 < 4n^2 + 1$ we are done.

Proving $8n + 4 < 4n^2 + 1$ looks easiest.

$8n + 4 < 4n^2 + 1 \iff 3 < 4n^2 - 8n = 4n(n - 2)$.  As $n \ge 6$, $n - 2 \ge 4$ and $4n \ge 24$ and $4n(n-2) \ge 96 > 3$.

....

So that was noodling.  To put it all together:

====

1)  Base step:  Prove if $n =6$ then $4n^2 + 1 < 3*2^n$

Pf: $4n^2 + 1 = 4*6^2 + 1 = 145$ and $3*2^n = 3*2^6 = 192$ and so $4n^2 + 1 = 145 < 192 = 3*2^n$.

2) Induction step: Prove that if $4n^2 + 1 < 3*2^n$ then $4(n+1)^2 + 1 < 3*2^{n+1}$.

Pf: $3*2^{n+1} = 3*2^n*2 = 3*2^n + 3*2^n >$

$(4n^2 + 1) + (4n^2 + 1) = $

$4n^2 + 4n^2 + 2 \ge $

$4n^2 + 4*6n + 2 =$

$4n^2 + 8n + 16n + 2 \ge$

$4n^2 + 8n + 16*6 + 2 =$

$4n^2 + 8n + 4 +94 = $

$4(n^2 + 2n + 1)  + 1 + 93=$

$4(n+1)^2 + 1 + 93 > $

$4(n+1)^2 + 1$

3).  We have prove that if $4n^2 + 1 < 3*2^n$ the is true for any natural number $n$, then it will be true for the succeeding natural number; $n+1$.  And we have proven that $4n^2 + 1 < 3*2^n$ is true for $n = 6$.  Therefore we can assumme through successive iterations that it is true for all $n \ge 6$.